# Huawei App Signing download .aab files without certificate

Tags: huawei-developers

I want to upload applications in .aab format. But when uploading the file, I am forced to upload the certificate. The question is, is it possible to upload aab painlessly like in the Google console? If not, can the certificate be uploaded via Api Publishing?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a certificate.pem file(forgot the procedure but will update soon)

1. Download pepk.jar
2. Create a folder(e.g Certificate)
3. Copy your keystore.jks(no spaces in the filename) file to the folder along with certificate.pem
4. Open command prompt and navigate to the folder
5. Run the command "java -jar pepk.jar --keystore keystoreName.jks --alias yourAlias --output=output.zip --encryptionkey=You'llFindThisInHuaweiAppGalleryConnectAppSigning --include-cert"

It will generate a file named output.zip and you'll upload that to AppGallery Connect

I'll update the answer for the certificate.pem